# How can I display the material-ui theme object in storybook

Tags: material-ui, themes, storybook

I would like to display our theme object in storybook somehow but haven't found a way to even look at theme from inside a component.

Minimally I would like something like what material-ui does showing the theme structure here: https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/

Idealy I would like to map through parts of the object and display colors, font sizes, font weights, spacing etc kind of like this (but it doesn't work because you can't access the theme like this)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => theme.palette.primary);

export const Primary = (): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(classes).map((key) => <Box bgcolor={classes[key]}>{key}</Box>)}
    </>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the mui.com website is open source, you can implement the minimum by copying the [source for the theme explorer](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/customization/default-theme/DefaultTheme.js) on the Default Theme page. You can see how they traverse the theme object, similar in a way to your code snippet.

If you only want to highlight parts of the theme file, you can traverse the object and use some inbuilt components like [`ColorPalette` from `@storybook/addon-docs`](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/lib/components/src/Colors/colorpalette.stories.mdx) for example. In the MUI project on the [palette page](https://mui.com/customization/palette/#default-values), they [manually pull out each color](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/customization/palette/Intentions.js#L48:L50) using `useTheme()`.

Maybe an storybook addon might be better placed? Example usage with MUI at the bottom of the page: https://storybook.js.org/addons/@react-theming/storybook-addon/